# Customize Emmet abreviation for JSX

Tags: sublimetext3, emmet

The following Emmet Shorthand `div.my-class[atrib1][atrib2]` will give me this.

`<div className="my-class" atrib1="" atrib2=""></div>`

However I'm using it with jsx, so I'd like to be able to return this if the attrib values are empty.

`<div className="my-class" atrib1 atrib2></div>`

So I can set boolean attributes using shorthand?

A bonus would be able to create `atrib1={}` instead of `atrib1=""`!

Answer (score 0):

2 hours lost for this...

Add:

```
{
  "syntaxProfiles": {
    "jsx": "html"
  }
}
```

To: `Emmet.sublime.settings`